# How to use map and set on Python

Tags: python, dictionary, set, coding-style

Is there a way to make this a bit cleaner?
I have to keep transforming everything to a list after doing an operation and this line of code is just bothering me. I'm kind of new to programming and wish to have something more presentable. This solution works for me, however it is a bit ugly.

```
exclusion_new = ["Abs", "acd", "bde", "Abs", "Kji"]  #example list
x = list(set(list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), exclusion_new))))
print(x)
result: ["abs", "acd", "bde", "kji"]
```

Comment: "I have to keep transforming everything to a list after doing an operation" No you don't. You *choose* to pointlessly put `list` around `map` when you can simply remove it. Why do you think it's required?

Comment: ln general, prefer comprehensions to `map`, so this could just be `list({x.lower() for x in exclusion_new})`

Comment: I'm not sure, i tried without it but it was giving an error, but hey, thanks! Gonna try that!

Comment: I heard it was a bit more efficient to use map rather than comprehensions, I'm not sure if that's true. What is the difference between then?

Comment: It definitely would not give you an error. Probably, you tried to use a `map` object in some other context, e.g. `my_map[0]`, which *did* raise an error, and you solved that by converting it to a list. But you should understand *why* that was necessary, not just automatically put `list` around every `map`...

Comment: You heard misinformation. It is **absolutely not** more efficient to use `map` over a comprehension. Comprehensions are generally *faster* since they can avoid calling a function for every iteration. Although it is a matter of style, idiomatically, comprehensions are preferred in Python (indeed, Guido wanted to remove `map`/`filter`/`reduce` in Python 3). A comprehension allows you to combine a map/filtering operation on arbitrary iterables to yield a specific type

Comment: Thank you, it makes absolute sense. I'm trying to improve and this will definetely help.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In this case it's true, though, map is faster than the comprehension [if done right](https://tio.run/##VY/LCsJADEX38xWhm86U4saNCC5cuPITSpE@Uh3pPMhEVMRvr52OCGYTcnIIuf7JF2fXG0/TNJAzwNqgZtDGO2Ig9NiwEAH55mEHOT668Ra0syeL9xlU2b4NWQlZ0/WxtT3G9oXHq87qXIhDNAXMlVfFqzCNl4FpNbo7Ugl/N9W7zsufGpIjFQyOIIC2//Yi10LE7SluqbFnlGu1XU5EjBEf0hyL51@MtjJFk1jCEk6pn@FJW5Y8P5ZYmtU0fQA).

Comment: Funny to see how such a basic question can create such a discussion, nice :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yes, when you are just calling a method over and over again, `map` can be faster because you skip the method resolution which has some overhead. In many cases, though, map requires you to wrap some expression in a function to provide to `map`, which will add overhead that won't be there with an equivalent comprehension. All of this is pretty small though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove one call of `list()`:

```
exclusion_new = ["Abs", "acd", "bde", "Abs", "Kji"]  #example list
x = list(set(map(lambda x: x.lower(), exclusion_new)))
```

Furthermore using a **map-function** in combination with **lambda** is **overkill** in this scenario.

You should use a simple **list comprehension** instead:

```
exclusion_new = ["Abs", "acd", "bde", "Abs", "Kji"]  #example list
x = set([x.lower() for x in exclusion_new])
```

Alternatively a **set comprehension**:

```
exclusion_new = ["Abs", "acd", "bde", "Abs", "Kji"]  #example list
x = [*{x.lower() for x in exclusion_new}]
```

Comment: Why when you use the "{}" in x = {x.lower() for x in exclusion_new} it eliminates the duplicates?

Comment: @LuísHenriqueMartins Because **sets** in Python do not allow duplicates to exist, they get eradicated.  https://realpython.com/python-sets/

Comment: Oh okay, @Bialomazur. I did not know that {} is a set, I thought I had to call it set(), but it is just like creating a list with [] and calling list(). Thanks!

Comment: @LuísHenriqueMartins  Yes exactly - the only thing you have to bare in mind ist that {} can also define a **dict**, depending with what values you instantiate the object. For instance {"key":""value"} would result in a **dict** and {1,2,3,4} would give you a **set**.

Answer (score 4):

You could make it more concise using unpacking for the list and passing str.lower to the map function:

```
 x = [*{*map(str.lower, exclusion_new)}]
```

Comment: would it be faster to use `set` instead of `{}`?

Comment: I find this an abuse of the iterable unpacking, which is really meant for things like `[foo, *some_iterable, bar, baz]` instead of `[*some_iterable]`... this idiomatic way to do that is to use `list(some_iterable)`. It is definitely more readable. For the record, I did not downvote

Comment: Not noticeably, I personally prefer using `set()` rather than `{*...}` for clarity (but it's 2 more characters if conciseness is the objective)

Comment: @Matiiss No, [slower](https://tio.run/##fY@7CgIxEEX7fMWwzSay2NiIYGFh5SfIIquOOrJ5MBlREb99TYwINk5zmcNhHuEuJ@8m08DDcGBvQcgiCZANngUYA3aiVES5BJhDjbddf4nk3cbhNYF1tdjGqoGq2@1zbPeY4wNXZ6raWqllNhWkqtejx8h2QUfhce@vyA38zDTPtm6K2lMUnTbrv74xyW@VOniGDZAD7twR9cTM3lMyxoyXpc8l6RxLTpfvNDbw/s@YrxGYnGhJuworvRmGFw).